# Persisting Facebook data into Mongodb (Node.js + Express + jade)

Tags: facebook, node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing simple web app that asks for Facebook access token and retrieve 'post' data of logged-in user.

After clicking 'login', it calls FB.api to retrieve user posts and use innerHTML in javascript to update user-status:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="user-info"></div>
<div id="user-email"></div>
<div id="user-status" name="post"></div>
<button id="fb-auth">Login</button>
```

My goal is to persist these updated data into mongodb.

What i have tried is to force to submit the form when the post is retrieved and pass the data in 'name="post"', However, this makes the page refreshes again and also the value shows undefined.

Javascript:

```
FB.api('/me/posts', { limit: 100 }, function(response) {
            var userStatus = document.getElementById('user-status');
            for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
              var post = response.data[i];
              if (post.message) {
                userStatus.innerHTML = userStatus.innerHTML + ' ' + post.message ;

                var form = document.createElement('form');
                form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
                form.style.display = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

              } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
                alert('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
              }
            }             
          });
```

app.js(req.param('post') is undefined, thus mongodb injects undefined data):

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  postProvider.save({
    posts: req.param('post')
  }, function(error, docs){
    res.redirect('/')
  });
});
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get form data you have to use:

```
req.body.post
```